# Exchange vowels from user input in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, input

I want to have the user input a sentence and have the program print out the same sentence **except** having the vowels swapped as follows:

- A = E
- E = I
- I = O
- O = U
- U = A

I have started writing the following code, but is there a more efficient way to do this other than telling the program what to do for every single letter?

```
inp = input("Enter a sentence: ")
for letter in inp:
    if letter == "a":
        print("e", end = "")
    if letter == "b":
        print("b", end = "")
    if letter == "c":
        print("c", end = "")
    if letter == "d":
        print("d", end = "")
    if letter == "e":
        print("i", end = "")
    if letter == "f":
        print("f", end = "")
    if letter == "g":
        print("g", end = "")
    if letter == "i":
        print("o", end = "")
    if letter == "o":
        print("u", end = "")
    if letter == "u":
        print("a", end = "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way would be using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) (with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)):

```
>>> inp = input("Enter a sentence: ")
>>> print(inp.translate(str.maketrans('AaEeIiOoUu', 'EeIiOoUuAa')))
Enter a sentence: hello YOU
Hillu YUA
```

---

But if you want to keep away from the `str`-methods you could use a `dict` instead of all these `if`s:

```
change = {'A': 'E', 'a': 'e',
          'E': 'I', 'e': 'i',
          'I': 'O', 'i': 'o',
          'O': 'U', 'o': 'u',
          'U': 'A', 'u': 'a'}

for char in inp:
    print(change.get(char, char), end='')
```

This looks up if the character is in the `change` dictionary and if it is contained it prints it's value, otherwise the default (the second argument for [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) - the original char) is printed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest and easiest ways to achieve this is using a dictionary.

Create a dictionary where keys are the characters to remove, and the values are the characters to insert:

```
characters_to_swap = {'a':'e', 'e':'i', 'i':'o', 'o':'u', 'u':'a'}
```

Then iterate over the input:

```
data = input()
for character in data:
    if character in characters_to_swap:
        print(characters_to_swap[character], end='')
    else:
        print(character, end='')
```

Don't worry too much about the `end` parameter in `print`, it just corresponds to the last character printed. I set it to `''` so it does not print a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = input("Enter a sentence: ").lower()
output = ""
letters = {"a":"e", "e":"i", "i":"o", "o":"u", "u":"a"}
for letter in inp:
    if letter in letters:
        output = output + letters[letter]
    else:
        output = output + letter
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more clear answer, but not the most compact answer.
Using dictionaries, allow you to map `str` characters to others and exchange them by making a list out of the input.

```
inp = list(input("Enter a sentence: "))
letter_swap = {'A': 'E', 'E': 'I', 'I': 'O', 'O' : 'U', 'U' : 'A', 'a' : 'e', 'e' : 'i', 'i' : 'o', 'o' : 'u', 'u' : 'a'}

for i, letter in enumerate(inp):
    if letter in letter_swap:
         inp[i] = letter_swap[letter]

inp = ''.join(inp)

print(inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness...

Here is a one-liner using `lambda` functions:

```
(lambda s: (lambda t, d: print("".join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in t)))(s, {'a':'e', 'e':'i', 'i':'o', 'o':'u', 'u':'a'}))(input("Enter a string: "))
```

This is however pretty hard to read, and even harder to debug.

This solution though uses concepts that are far off the basic problem that was asked (imbricated `lambda` functions, `lambda` function evaluation, generators, in-line `if...else`, the `join` method...), but I find it pretty interesting, because it produces a one-liner.